# Crossterm not clearing screen properly

Tags: rust, tui, crossterm

I have a main method that looks like this:

```rust
use std::io::stdout;
use crossterm as ct;
use crossterm::terminal as ct_terminal;

pub mod tui;

fn main() -> () {
    let user_result: usize = tui::select_choice("", &[]);
}
```

The function that's called (`tui::select_choice()`) looks like this:

```rust
use std::{thread::sleep, time::Duration};
use crossterm::terminal::{Clear, ClearType::Purge};
use crossterm::ExecutableCommand;
use std::io::stdout;

pub fn select_choice(pre_text: &str, options: &[&str]) -> usize {
    println!("Na");
    sleep(Duration::from_secs(5));
    stdout().execute(Clear(Purge));
    println!("ima do my own thing");
    sleep(Duration::from_secs(5));
    2 as usize
}
```

The program runs but the terminal won't clear. It just prints on the next line:

```
Na
ima do my own thing

H:\Code\Rust\GTFO>
```

Comment: Please post a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @ChayimFriedman made it a complete script and removed anything else that didn't seem important

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Contrary to the documentation ([`ClearType::Purge`](https://docs.rs/crossterm/latest/crossterm/terminal/enum.ClearType.html#variant.Purge) - "All plus history"), `Purge` clears *only* history, not the screen. It also sends ANSI escape `ESC[3J`, which means "erase history", not "clear screen" (although confusingly, on Windows <10 it does seem to clear to screen - doesn't have a machine to test that on, though).

If you want to clear history + screen, you need to send both `Purge` and `All`.

Comment: Clearing with `ClearType::All` and then `ClearType::Purge` seems to work. Althought, I don't know if `Purge` is what I want since I don't know what "clears history" means since I assumed `All` cleared the screen as well. Regardless, it works. Appreciate the response.

Comment: @Ex0tic_Python "Clear history" means clearing the scroll bar (all lines above current shown screen).